# Put the footer under head

Tags: css

Here is my problem:
I have head.php page I include on every page of my website and a footer.php page I include at the end of every page.

The basic layout is on the head.php file:
http://prntscr.com/5jbn1b

And here is my problem:
http://prntscr.com/5jbmnf

As you can see, my footer is behind the head div.
Here my code:

***style.css:***

```
/*Base Debut*/
#base {
    background-color:white;
    height:auto;
    width:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
/*Base Fin*/

/*Footer Debut*/
#foot {
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #303030;
    width: 1000px;
    color: #7A7A7A;
    font-family: OswaldL;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

#foot .under {
    background-color: #2B2B2B;
    width:1000px;
    height:10px;
}
/*Footer Fin*/
```

***head.php:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>WEBSITE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="connect">
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Inscription</a> <a href="#">Connexion</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
<div id="base">
    <section style="color: black;">
        <nav class="gauche" style="margin-top: 55px;">
            <h1>$rubrique1</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="membres.php">Membres</a></li>
                <li><a href="stats.php">Statistiques</a></li>
            </ul>

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['pseudo']))
                {
            ?>

            <h1>$rubrique0</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="messagerie.php">Messages privés</a></li>
                <li><a href="options.php">Options</a></li>
                <li><a href="connexion.php?inverted">Déconnexion</a></li>
            </ul>

            <?php
                }   
            ?>

            <h1>$rubrique2</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="news.php">$inter1</a></li>
                <li><a href="album.php">$inter2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <h1>$rubrique3</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="equipe.php">$lien1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="droite" style="color: black; float: right;">
            <h1>$droite1</h1>
            <div class="droite_text">
                <li><a href="forum.php?id=1">$forum1</a></li>
            </div>

            <h1>$droite2</h1>
            <div class="droite_text">
            $connectes
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

***footer.php:***

```
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </section>  
        <div id="foot">

            <?php echo NOM_SITE; ?> © | $footercredit <a href="#">$dev1</a> et <a href="#">$dev2</a> | $version <br />
            <a target="_blank" href="mobile">Version mobile</a>


        <div class="under">
        </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base code is position: absolute. Which essentially means anything that comes after it, will pop up behind it unless it was directed to be in another location. Absolute typically ignores all other divs and places itself wherever it wants.

There are a couple of ways you can change this behavior, but the easiest based on what you're showing here is change #base to not be position: absolute.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I put the footer under the #base (located in the header)?